# Setting Up SVN:Externals with TortoiseSVN in Windows

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I'm trying to set up `svn:externals` with TortoiseSVN on a Windows machine. I have two projects and both repositories have been already created on the same local machine.

The current structure looks like this. I created `repoA`, `repoB` for repositories and `workA` and `workB` for working directories (checkouts).

**Repositories**

> Z:\repos\repoA
>
> Z:\repos\repoB

**Working Directories**

> Z:\Projects\workA\trunk\core.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workA\trunk\lib\lib01.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\core_mod.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\lib\

(there are `tags` and `branches` folders but they are omitted to keep the question simple.)

What I'd like to achieve is the file(s) under `workA\trunk\lib\` in this case `lib01.php` to be automatically copied into the `workB\trunk\lib\` directory.

In order to set this up, what I've done is as follows:

1. Checked out `workA` and assigned it to `repoA` and checked out `workB` and assigned it to `repoB`
2. Comitted the `workA\trunk` folder so the `repoA` is up to date.
3. In oreder to assign an import location for `workB\trunk\lib`, right clicked on the `workB` folder and chose `TortoiseSVN -> Properties`.
4. Clicked on `New -> Externals` and clicked `New...`
5. typed `./trunk/lib` in the `Local path` form field. For the `URL` field, typed `file:///Z:/repos/repoA/trunk/lib`. By pressing the `...` button, repo-browser opened and helped to select the target folder.

   [image]

   [image]
6. Clicked `Ok` a few times to close the settings windows. I assumed the externals setting was done.
7. Created a file, `Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\core_mod.php`
8. Right clicked on `Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\` and selected `SVN Comit` to comit the `workB` to `repoB`.

I expected at this point, the lib01.php would be automatically imported in the `Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\lib` folder but nothing is copied. I also tried `SVN Update` by right clicking on the `workB\trunk` folder. But the `workB\trunk\lib` folder kept empty.

I suspect the relative path `./trunk/lib` must be mistaken. I don't know. If you can point out what I'm doing wrong, it would be appreciated.

**Update**

> 6a - commit changed Working Copy WorkB to repo

This was a blind spot for me. I right clicked on `Z:\Projects\workB` and selected `SVN Commit...` and it gave the following error.

[image]

After clicking the OK button immediately I got a dialog window asking whether to update the folder and I clicked OK. Then TortoiseSVN started updating `Z:\Projects\workB` and I got this error. But after this, when I re-commited `Z:\Projects\workB`, it went through without an error.

[image]

> ("trunk/lib" in your case will be more bulletproof, I suppose).

Thanks, when I reselected `Property` of the `workB` folder and clicked on the `Edit` button for the `svn:externals`, TortoiseSVN automatically adjusted `./trunk/lib` to `trunk/lib`. Now it is set to be so.

> 6b - test with repobrowser on RepoB (just fastest way), that definition is correct

I right clicked on `Z:\repos\repoB` and chose `TortoiseSVN -> repo-browser` and browsed down to the trunk folder. It looks as follows. Does it look right? I really don't know since I never had worked on this task. The lib folder under the trunk folder is empty in the repo-browser.

[image]

The `Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\lib` folder is still empty. The error message suggests to relocate 'Z:\Projects\workB' but I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Repo-Broswer show **two** lib folders inside trunk - one external and one real (not needed) - it's problem. Try fresh checkout of trunk (fully recursive, with externals) in order to see current state of repo

Comment: `Repo-Broswer show two lib folders inside trunk - one external and one real (not needed) - it's problem.` - This was it. Thanks. I deleted the real `lib` folder in the repo-browser, `Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\lib`, and performed `SVN Update` on `Z:\Projects\workB`. Now `Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\lib\lib01.php` was automatically created. This was a really long journey to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot at least one mandatory action

6a - commit changed Working Copy WorkB to repo

and one optional checkpoint

6b - test with repobrowser on RepoB (just fastest way), that definition is correct

Can't recall why, but I never use ./ in path-spec for URLs in TSVN ("trunk/lib" in your case will be more bulletproof, I suppose). And pure personal habits - I define external at the point of mount, even if as result I get multiple definitions inside repo instead one aggregated in root

Repo-browser with external in tree and definition shown

[image: Repo-Browser]

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who comes across this issue, the working directory of workB did not need the importing folder.

> Z:\Projects\workA\trunk\core.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workA\trunk\lib\lib01.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\core_mod.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\lib\

had to be

> Z:\Projects\workA\trunk\core.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workA\trunk\lib\lib01.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\core_mod.php
>
> Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\

( no Z:\Projects\workB\trunk\lib)

Comment: really you *can* (theoretically, I'm too lazy for testing) have **real lib** folder and **externals inside** it's root, if: 1. you'll create external definition for LIB folder 2. Mount path will be "."

Comment: Interesting. Sounds a bit complicated for my current understanding level though. Probably the information would be helpful for other advanced users. Thanks for your input.